# QTableWidget as child in QTreeView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qtreeview

I have a QTreeView which populates from a QAbstractItemModel via a QSortFilterProxyModel.

I've implemented a DataStructure class that sets Parent / Child relationships for the data and a TreeView(QAbstractItemModel) class - this works well and populates the QTreeView as I want.

The treeView is set like:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import data_Model

#DataStructure(data, parent=None)
rootNode = data_Model.DataStructure('_Holder')

for i in mainData:
    mainRow = data_Model.DataStructure(i, rootNode)
    for j in subData:
        data_Model.DataStructure(j, mainRow)

self._proxyModel = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
self._model = data_Model.TreeModel(rootNode)
self._proxyModel.setSourceModel(self._model)

self.treeView.setModel(self._proxyModel)
```

I want to change this so that subData is populated in a QTableWidget that is a child of the relevant mainRow for a specific column index

My attempt is to remove:

```
    for j in subData:
        data_Model.DataStructure(j, mainRow)
```

from the above, and call the below each time the main model is set:

```
def addChild(self, subData):

    rowCount = self._proxyModel.rowCount()
    widgetDict = {}

    for i in range(rowCount):

        for j in range(len(subData)):

            #set model index as current row and column 5 onwards
            modelIndex = self._proxyModel.mapToSource(self._proxyModel.index(i, 5 + j))
            widgetDict[str(i) + str(j)] = QtGui.QListWidget().addItems(subData[j])

            self.treeView.setIndexWidget(modelIndex, widgetDict[str(i) + str(j)])
```

The setIndexWidget call seems to have no effect. I'm sure this is a completely backward way to go about this but my attempts to include the QListWidget within the data_Model have failed miserably. Any direction on how to go about this (or if possible!) or specific advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the rest of the code, but the line:

```
    widgetDict[str(i) + str(j)] = QtGui.QListWidget().addItems(subData[j])
```

will create and populate a list-widget, then throw it away and add `None` to `widgetDict`.

You probably want something more like:

```
    widget = QtGui.QListWidget()
    widget.addItems(subData[j])
    widgetDict[str(i) + str(j)] = widget
    self.treeView.setIndexWidget(modelIndex, widget)
```

Comment: Thanks - still not working. The reason I had it like this was due to the following form the PySide documentation: If index widget A is replaced with index widget B, index widget A will be deleted. For example, in the code snippet below, the PySide.QtGui.QLineEdit object will be deleted.

setIndexWidget(index, QLineEdit())
...
setIndexWidget(index, QTextEdit())

Comment: @lorgan. I don't see the relevance of that. The point is that `addItems` always returns `None`, and my answer fixes that one issue. But there are probably other issues with your example. To begin with, what is the purpose of `widgetDict`? Do you keep a reference to it? If not, you will have to make sure all the index widgets are given a parent, otherwise they will just get garbage-collected (I have updated my answer slightly to deal with that).

Comment: I was attempting to address the issue above from the PySide documentation with the widgetDict... so I guess it does nothing. Adding the parent to the widget instantiation adds the widget to the top left corner of the treeView - the setIndexWidget command still does nothing

Comment: @lorgan. That probably indicates that the model-index you are passing to `setIndexWidget` is invalid. (And on second thoughts, my previous advice about needing to give the widgets a parent is wrong, since the view will take ownership of the widget).

Comment: So something wrong with this line: modelIndex = self._proxyModel.mapToSource(self._proxyModel.index(i, 5 + j))? The modelIndex type = <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QModelIndex'> and model = <data_Model.TreeModel object at 0x05C6F2B0>... it seems valid?

Comment: @lorgan. That tells you nothing about the validity of the index. The view will consider it valid if `index.row()` and `index.column()` are equal to or greater than zero, and if `index.model() is view.model()`. You could also do `print(self.treeView.indexWidget(modelIndex))` to check whether it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @ekhumoro modelIndex.model() and treeView.model() need to be the same. I was trying to map the _proxyModel back to the _model and that was the issue

Changing this:

```
modelIndex = self._proxyModel.mapToSource(self._proxyModel.index(i, 5 + j))
```

to this:

```
modelIndex = self._proxyModel.index(i, 5 + j))
```

solved the problem